# applicationContext not loading properties that are paths to some files

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, applicationcontext

I have an application context file in `META-INF` folder of a project.

The directory tree:

```
├── src
    ├── main
    │   .
        .
        .
        .
        .

    └── test
        ├── java
            .   
            .   
            .   
            .   
            .   

        └── resources
            ├── META-INF
            │   ├── applicationContext.annotation.config.xml
            │   ├── applicationContext.annotationTestCase.config.xml
            │   └── applicationContext.xml
            │
            ├── annotation.properties
            ├── annotationTestCase.properties
            ├── query.properties
            └── project.properties
```

In the `applicationContext.xml` I have a property:

```
<property name="propFile" value="annotation.properties"/>
```

I use this property in a java file like `private String propFile;`. `propFile` is basically a path to the properties file which is loaded into the program. But as soon as I load I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: annotation.properties
```

I also printed the value of `propsFile` which was `annotation.properties`.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: The path is in your classpath and not a regular file, I suggest using Springs Resource abstraction to load the files instead of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Its just not the file name, check the file path you are trying to read from.

```
// From ClassLoader, all paths are "absolute" already - there's no context
// from which they could be relative. Therefore you don't need a leading slash.
   InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("annotation.properties");
```

That's not good coding , but use spring instead. PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer to load any property file

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>annotation.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If you want that the name "annotation.properties" to be dynamic, then pass it from system property.

java -DpropertyFilePath=/path/to/propertyfile